# Function Template Argument Deduction

Tags: c++

I'm reading Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 687, Section *Function Template Argument Deduction* and have a question.  I see that `T(*)(args)` is listed and Stroustrup says per picture below that "args is a parameter list that does not allow deduction".

I have attached the following code where args does appear to allow deduction.  Does anyone know what Stroustrup means here?  Perhaps I'm not interpreting this correctly.  Thanks for your guidance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename U>
void f(const T*, U(*)(U))
{
}

int g(int x) {return x;};
int h(double x) {return x;};

void h(const char *p)
{
    f(p,g);
    // f(p,h); // error: no matching function for call to 'f'
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    h("");
}
```

Graphic from Stroustrup:
[image: Stroustrup Graphic]

Comment: I *think* (thus not writing an answer), that it just slipped. `type(*)(args_TI)` is included, so I think `T(*)(args_TI)` was supposed to be there as well. Member function pointer has all permutations, I don't see any reason why a normal function pointer should not have them.